# QUERY FAILED .You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds

Tags: php, mysql

Edit the post in CMS.
i am getting the error.

> (QUERY FAILED .You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
>   to use near 'post_tags = 'thing, about, learning', post_content = 'The
>   beautiful thing abou' at line 1 )

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['p_id'])) {

$the_post_id = $_GET['p_id'];

}


$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = $the_post_id ";
$select_posts_by_id = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_posts_by_id)) {
    $post_id = $row['post_id'];
    $post_title = $row['post_title'];
    $post_category_id = $row['post_category_id'];
    $post_image = $row['post_image'];
    $post_content = $row['post_content'];
    $post_date = $row['post_date'];
    $post_tags = $row['post_tags'];
    $post_comment_count = $row['post_comment_count'];
    $post_status = $row['post_status'];


}


if(isset($_POST['update_post'])) {


    $post_title = $_POST['post_title'];
    $post_category_id = $_POST['post_category'];
    $post_tags = $_POST['post_tags']; 
    $post_status = $_POST['post_status']; 
    $post_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $post_image_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $post_content = $_POST['post_content'];

move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "../images/$post_image");


        $query = "UPDATE posts SET ";
        $query .="post_title = '{$post_title}', "; 
        $query .="post_category_id = '{$post_category_id}', "; 
        $query .="post_tags  = '{$post_tags }', ";  
        $query .="post_status  = '{$post_status }', ";  
        $query .="post_image  = '{$post_image}' "; 
        $query .="post_tags  = '{$post_tags }', "; 
        $query .="post_content  = '{$post_content }', ";  
        $query .="post_comment_count  = '{$post_comment_count }', "; 
        $query .="WHERE post_id = {$the_post_id} ";

    $update_post = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

    confirmQuery($update_post);

}

?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="form-group">
<label for="title">Post Title</label>
<input value="<?php echo $post_title; ?>" type="text" class="form-control" name="post_title">
</div>


     <div class="form-group">

    <select name="post_category" id=""> 

    <?php

    $query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
    $select_categories = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

    confirmQuery($select_categories);      

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_categories )) {
    $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
    $cat_title = $row['cat_title'];

    echo "<option value='$cat_id'>{$cat_title}</option>"; 

    }

    ?>


    </select>
    </div>






     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_tags">Post tags </label>
        <input value="<?php echo $post_tags; ?>" type="text" class="form-control" name="post_tags">
        </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_status">Post status</label>
        <input value="<?php echo $post_status; ?>"  type="text" class="form-control" name="post_status">
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
        <img width="100" src="../images/<?php echo $post_image; ?>" alt="">
        <input type="file" name="image">
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_content">Post Content</label>
        <textarea class="form-control "name="post_content" id"" cols="30" rows="10"><?php echo $post_content; ?></textarea>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="update_post" value="Update Post">
        </div>



</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update statement is missing a comma

```
    $query = "UPDATE posts SET ";
    $query .="post_title = '{$post_title}', "; 
    $query .="post_category_id = '{$post_category_id}', "; 
    $query .="post_tags  = '{$post_tags}', ";  
    $query .="post_status  = '{$post_status}', ";  
    $query .="post_image  = '{$post_image}', "; /* MISSING COMMA */
    $query .="post_tags  = '{$post_tags}', "; 
    $query .="post_content  = '{$post_content}', ";  
    $query .="post_comment_count  = '{$post_comment_count}' "; /* EXTRA, uneeded comma */
    $query .="WHERE post_id = {$the_post_id}";
```

and an unneeded extra comma before the where clause. Additionally extra spaces before closing curly braces might cause issues. If you were to write the sql like this you can spot issues easier imo.

```
    $query = "UPDATE posts SET 
                post_title = '{$post_title}',
                post_tags  = '{$post_tags }', 
                post_status  = '{$post_status}',
                post_image  = '{$post_image}',
                post_tags  = '{$post_tags}',
                post_content  = '{$post_content}',
                post_comment_count  = '{$post_comment_count}'
                WHERE post_id = {$the_post_id}";
```

Comment: Thank u very much Mr. RamRaider